# How to separate the values inside bloginfo( 'name' ) in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, string

The site title / logo of the WordPress site I was working on is displayed under this code snippet.

```
    <h2 class="site-title">
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
    <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>
</a></h2>
```

However, the font-family styling of each letter under the

```
<?php bloginfo( 'name' )
```

is not the same on the entire phrase (eg. a letter "a" has a different font-family than the rest).

How do I make it such that each value inside bloginfo('name') is checked so that a letter "a" is given a different CSS styling and the rest remains the same?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean the first letter of name? Or you mean to say all letters 'a' in a name?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way, replace your:

```
<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>
```

with this one:

```
<?php 
$bloginfo_name = get_bloginfo('name'); 
$bloginfo_name = str_replace('a', '<span>a</span>', $bloginfo_name );
echo $bloginfo_name;
?>
```

And then just add some class/style to that span :)